# Get unique pairs of elements from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got an ArrayList which contains a series of integers (represnting indices in another ArrayList).

I need to extract each Unique pair eg...

```
ArrayList = 1,4,5,7
```

I need:

```
1:4
1:5
1:7
4:5
4:7
5:7
```

What's the simplest method of achieving this?

Comment: @SimplyPanda Not a lot - This is something that's obviously very simple. I could go about it by pushing things onto an array as they're checked but it seems like overkill. This is for someone else's code in a very simple physics engine. We've pared down the objects in a particular grid and need to efficiently choose pairs to test for collision. Since this seems like it should be a 1-liner, I was hoping someone could give me a quick answer

Comment: Are you looking for an easy to implement or efficient? How many iters has that array?

Comment: @ssedano Potentially a couple of thousand

Comment: Are the input lists going to contain duplicates? e.g. `1,1,4,7`?

Comment: @Basic for such a small amount Jigar Joshi answer would suite you

Comment: @ftr good point but no, not in this case - I agree I should've mentioned that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

convert list to `Set` and back to `List` for unique filtering

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i ++){
  for(int j = i+1 ; j < list.size(); j ++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i) + "," + .list.get(j))    
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the first for loop should be `list.size() - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Well loop through all possible choices for the first element. For each of those, loop through all possible choices for the second.

I'll leave the finding duplicates part up to you (hint: use a `Set`).

Answer (score 0):

You could have two indices: one for the first part, the other for the second.  Then interate through with the first form the beginning to the one-but-last element, and in an inner loop iterate through with the second from one-past-the first to the end.

Comment: @SeanOwen - why so?  the second always starts from after the first, so no pairs are encountered more than once -- see Jigar's answer, it's essentially the same

Comment: Because the original list may have duplicate values -- but, the OP just clarified that it won't. If so yes this is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using a graph structure with unidirectional relation would suit this problem.

It is way much work than a simple permutation, but probably more interesting to implement. Specially for a large number of pairs.

Comment: I would not throw a database at such a simple problem